# apollo gateway (federation) fails to connect to services in kubernetes environment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apollo, apollo-federation

I have experience with graphql but its my first time trying apollo federation and kubernetes.

I first tried splitting my monolith graphql server to micro services using apollo federation.
It worked fine(below is the working code). Now I am trying to run these micro services in kubernetes cluster, but keep having network problems between the apollo gateway and the other backend services.

From the apollo gateway server(when i try running it on kubernetes), I get this error:

`Encountered error when loading auth at auth-cluster-ip-service: Only absolute URLs are supported`

This is the part where I services are added to the apollo gateway:

```
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  serviceList: [
    { name: 'service1', url: process.env.SERVICE1_URL },
    { name: 'service2', url: process.env.SERVICE2_URL },
    { name: 'service3', url: process.env.SERVICE3_URL },
  ],
  buildService({ name, url }) {
    return new AuthenticatedDataSource({ name, url });
  }
});
```

First I tried, with the following environment variables

```
(.env)
SERVICE1_URL =http://localhost:3051
SERVICE2_URL =http://localhost:3052
SERVICE3_URL =http://localhost:3053
```

I simply ran 4 node apps on localhost on my laptop and it works!

Now the kubernetes part.

Below is the deployment config file for apollo-gateway. I am suspecting that the problem lies within the environment variables. As you can see, instead of an `url`, I have the `service name` on the corresponding environment variables' values. But from what I have learned, kubernetes master will fetch this "url"(clusterIP name) and replace with the IP address of the corresponding pods. So it should be fine.

It worked well when I practiced kubernetes. In my practice I was connecting to redis and postgres pods, via clusterIP name.

apollo-gateway deploymant config file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gateway-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: gateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: gateway
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: gateway
          image:<docker-id>/gateway
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4000
          env:
            - name: ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
              value: fas69dO2Z15nkev6157
            - name: SERVICE1_URL
              value: service1-cluster-ip-service
            - name: SERVICE2_URL
              value: service1-cluster-ip-service
            - name: SERVICE3_URL
              value: service1-cluster-ip-service
```

sample SERVICE cluster-ip config file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service1-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: service1
  ports:
    - port: 3051
      targetPort: 3051
```

sample SERVICE deployment config file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service1-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: service1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: service1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image:<docker-id>/service1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3051
```

Comment: The error message suggests you need to use complete working URLs; `http://service1-cluster-ip-service:3051`.

Comment: I tried that and still get an error: `Encountered error when loading auth at http://service1-cluster-ip-service:3051: request to http://service1-cluster-ip-service:3051/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.107.81.47:3051`

Comment: @DavidMaze wow.. That actually worked.. I was very silly. Its a completely different issue. Basically I need to have other services running prior the api gateway is launched. For now, temporarily I have added `setTimeout` to solve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: @SihoonKim your service and deployment seems ok from kubernetes perspective, do you have any way to test if that token is correct? you can try `kubectl run -it --rm ubuntu --generator=run-pod/v1 --image=ubuntu -- /bin/bash` to run a ubuntu pod and test your connection manually from inside the pod issuing `apt update && apt install curl -y` and trying to `curl` your request to `http://service1-cluster-ip-service:3051` with your authorization token. Let me know if you can connect manually to the service.

Comment: @DavidMaze pointed out the problem and with a tweak in apollo gateway server it works!

Comment: Do not edit "SOLVED" into your question or title. Instead, add an answer with the "Add An Answer" button, and accept it when allowed.

Comment: ...or, if the solution was such that the question/answer pair is unlikely to be helpful to others, consider just deleting the question (the link to do so is near the "edit" link).

Comment: @DavidMaze would you write your comment that solved the case as an answer in order to help others with similar issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the error message says "only absolute URLs are supported", that means the configured URL needs to include the `http://` scheme part as well as the host name.  You can fix this by changing your environment settings to include that

```
- name: SERVICE1_URL
  value: 'http://service1-cluster-ip-service'
```

If the Service is listening on something other than the default HTTP port 80 you'll also need to include that port number in the URL.